# How to make segmented control like this

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

Today I'm creating a custom segmented control. The appearance of the control as follow:

[image]

I tried two methods:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage 
                  forState:(UIControlState)state 
                barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics

- (void)setDividerImage:(UIImage *)dividerImage 
    forLeftSegmentState:(UIControlState)leftState 
      rightSegmentState:(UIControlState)rightState 
             barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

However, here is the result I got:
[image]

I extracted the border image and the divider line (vertical line) from the design, but the result looks bad. Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: For kinda start-up to understanding you could check out this [link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/). There you could find lot's of customise view including UISegment. So might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have always found it too much work to customize the `UISegmentedControl` and it is not really fully customizable.
I suggest you create yourself a custom UIView inheriting 3 buttons. They are fully customizable and fully controllable:

```
#define BASE_TAG 123

NSArray *titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MAP", @"LOCATIONS", @"BUS", nil];

double y = 0.0;
double x = 0.0;
double width = (frame.size.width / [titles count]);
double height = frame.size.height;

for (int i = 0; i < [titles count]; i++)
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [button.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button setTag:(BASE_TAG + ([titles count] - i - 1))];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_buttons addObject:button];

    x += width;
}
```

This is your button action. Here the button clicked will be selected and all others unselected:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSInteger index = 0;

    for (UIButton *btn in self.subviews)
    {
        if (btn == button)
        {
            index = (btn.tag - BASE_TAG);
            [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#5ac8f5" alpha:1.0]];
            [btn setSelected:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [btn setSelected:NO];
        }
    }

    /* Trigger a delegate here if you like
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedIndex:)])
    {
        [_delegate didSelectedIndex:index];
    }
    */
}
```

This lets you pre set a selected index:

```
- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    for (UIButton *button in self.subviews)
    {
        if (button.tag == (BASE_TAG + index))
        {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#5ac8f5" alpha:1.0]];
            [button setSelected:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [button setSelected:NO];
        }

    }
}
```

This is just a suggestion code I pulled from an old project. You will have to customize it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I like your solution very much. I'm doing that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [very good article](http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/) how to do custom segmented control.
Looks like you have tried similar approach but you have messed up something with images (probably you misunderstand the API so this article should do the job for you).

Comment: This solution requires design skill that are not useful for me.